# iOS Region monitoring date

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, geolocation, core-location

I am trying to use region monitoring (aka geofencing) from Core Location on iOS.

After some testing with the function, I noticed that the date from the location data is the date where the event was generated and not the real date where the device entered or exited the region (ie. the callback from enter/exit region could be 5 min later after the device entered/exited the region).

Are there any ways to get real date of the location point where the device is actually entered or exited the region and not the date from event that was generate some minutes later?

Comment: The date of the event is when iOS determined that the device was inside or outside of the region; that is the date when the device "actually entered or exited the region". No other date is available from region monitoring.

Comment: If I understand correctly you mean that the date from the event is the delay date when iOS determined or validated that the device entry/exit the region.